# Loading anchor from url async doesnt work

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, combine, realitykit

Loading a anchor using LoadAnchorAsync(contentsOf: URL) does not work. Here is my code:

```
if let url = url {
    let loadRequest = Entity.loadAnchorAsync(contentsOf: url)
    _ = loadRequest.sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        // handle completion
    }, receiveValue: { anchor in
        self.arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
    })
} else {
        fatalError("no url")
}
```

but this crashes every time with an error:

Thread 27: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1051e0dfc)

[image]

Update: If i wrap the entire code block in an DispatchQueue.main.async block it doenst crash but neither reveiceCompletion or recieveValue gets called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store subscriber somewhere in member

```
// somewhere above
private var subscribers: Set<AnyCancellable>()

...
if let url = url {
    let loadRequest = Entity.loadAnchorAsync(contentsOf: url)
    loadRequest.sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        // handle completion
    }, receiveValue: { anchor in
        self.arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
    }).store(in: &self.subscribers) // << keep it alive
} else {
        fatalError("no url")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if let url = url {
    let loadRequest = try? Entity.load(contentsOf: url)
    _ = loadRequest.sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        // handle completion
    }, receiveValue: { anchor in
        self.arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
    })
} else {
        fatalError("no url")
}
```

Comment: Entity.load(contentsOf: url) does not return a LoadRequest because its not async